# Inner product question

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal

We are given an inner product of $\mathbb R^3$:

$f\left(\begin{pmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} y_1\\y_2\\y_3\end{pmatrix}\right) = 2x_1y_1+x_1y_2+y_2x_1+2x_2y_2+x_2y_3+y_3x_2+x_3y_3$

We are given a linear transformation $T$ such that:

$$T\begin{pmatrix} \;\;1\\\;\;0\\-1\end{pmatrix}=a\begin{pmatrix} \;\;1\\\;\;0\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$T\begin{pmatrix}\;\;0\\\;\;1\\-1\end{pmatrix}=b\begin{pmatrix}\;\;0\\\;\;1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$T\begin{pmatrix}\;\;1\\-1\\\;\;2\end{pmatrix}=c\begin{pmatrix}\;\;1\\-1\\\;\;2\end{pmatrix}$$

Show that $T=T^*$ with respect to $f$ if and only if $a=b$. Meaning, for all $v\in \mathbb R^3$, $f(Tv,v)=f(v,Tv)$ if and only if $a=b$

The intuition says let's do Gram-Schmidt, look at the matrix of $T$ with respect to that orthonormal basis, transpose it, and see they are equal if $a=b$. In practice, that didn't work.

Comment: Why do Gram-Schmidt in the first place? The 3 vectors given are a basis, so we know that wrt this basis, T's matrix representation $A$ is diag(a,b,c). If you calculate the representing matrix $F$ for $f(\cdot,\cdot)$, its Gramian, you should just need to check if $(FA)^T = F^T A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the vectors you're given the effect of T on are a basis for $ \mathbb{R}^3$ of eigenvectors of T. Since everything is linear, you need only prove that $f(Tv,w) = f(v,Tw)$ iff $a = b$ for $v, w$ a pair (that could be equal) of these basis vectors. Note that you do need the equation to hold with the vectors used on each side not equal.

Try substituting some of these combinations in and see if you get anywhere. I think (but haven't actually written out the algerba) that it should work.

Comment: something is not clear to me. I know I need to prove $f(Tv,v)=f(v,Tv)$ where $v \in \mathbb R^3$. Why is it enough to show it's true for the vectors of the given basis? and why do I need to show it for $v,w$ that are different?

Comment: Well, certainly every definition I've seen of $T^*$ has been that $<Tx,y> = <x,T^*y> \ \forall \ x,y$ - I don't believe that it's implied by the statement only for $x=y$. (using <,> for the inner product).

Comment: For the basis, note that $f(x+y,a+b) = f(x,a+b) + f(y,a+b) = f(x,a) + f(x,b) + f(y,a) + f(y,b)$, and $T(x+y) = Tx + Ty$. Also $f(\lambda x, \mu y) = \lambda \mu f(x,y)$ and $T(\lambda x) = \lambda Tx$ (for $\lambda , \mu$ scalars). Since you can express every vector in terms of the basis vectors, you can deduce statements for all vectors from that for the basis by splitting your arbitrary vector into this expression.